# Year to Year variation

Tags: r, correlation, lag

I have a question about how to calculate year to year correlations for certain statistics. Like I want to test whether two statistics (let's use a baseball example) whether for specific players is Average or On-Base Percentage more constant over time? Like which fluctuates more compared to the other.

My data currently is in the following format:

```
              name     Season      ARuns   Lag 1     BRuns  Lag BRuns
321           Abad Andy   2003     -1.05   NA       -1.19      NA
3158 Abercrombie Reggie   2006     27.42   NA        -.42     NA 
1312 Abercrombie Reggie   2007      7.65   27.42     .15     -.42
1069 Abercrombie Reggie   2008      5.34   7.65      -1.81     .15
4614    Abernathy Brent   2002     46.71   NA        -.86    NA
707     Abernathy Brent   2003     -2.29   46.71     -.33    -.86
1297    Abernathy Brent   2005      5.59   -2.29     3.53     -.33
6024        Abreu Bobby   2002    102.89   NA        2.70   NA
6087        Abreu Bobby   2003    113.23   102.89    4.39   2.70
6177        Abreu Bobby   2004    128.60   113.23    2.29   4.39
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Try comparing the variances of each player statistic. Higher variance means more volatility.

Comment: I have thought about that, but wouldn't that be affected by ranges of the statistic? ARuns is on a -5 to 130 type scale while BRuns is on a -2 to 8 scale. My idea right now is to look at the na.omit correlations between the actual value and the lag 1 value. Thoughts on that?

Comment: You could rescale both to the same range (e.g., 0-1) that should get around that problem.